# Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'void *' to parameter of type 'NSEnumerationOptions' (aka 'unsigned int')

Tags: objective-c, types, nsarray, warnings

How do I specify that I want to 'enumerateObjectsAtIndexes:` without any options? When I try to pass nil to the options argument, Xcode gives me this warning. What is the equivalent value that won't cause a complaint?

Answer (score 3):

`opts` is an enumeration which (in this case) is basically and `unsigned int`, so pass `0`.

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSEnumerationOptions

Read the NSArray docs on this method, then click the NSEnumerationOptions link in the description.

**NSEnumerationOptions**

Options for Block enumeration operations.

```
enum {
   NSEnumerationConcurrent = (1UL << 0),
   NSEnumerationReverse = (1UL << 1),
};
typedef NSUInteger NSEnumerationOptions;
```

Clearly it is an NSUInteger bit masked. 
0 or one or both of the above, though the `NSEnumerationConcurrent` is noted to be a hint only and not guaranteed.

`nil` is not an `NSUInteger`. Not all method parameters are objects. `nil` should only be passed when an object parameter is optional.